# In a cylic group of order $12$, we can find an element $g \in G$ such that $x^2 = g $ has no solutions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> $$ \textbf{PROBLEM} $$
>
> If $G = \{ g^n : 0 \leq n \leq 11 \} $. Then we can find an element $a
>  \in G$ such that the equation $x^2 = a$ has no solutions.

$$ \textbf{ATTEMPT} $$

My claim is that the multiples of $3$ would do. So, take $a = g^3$. We claim that $x^2 = g^3$ has no solutions. Suppose $b \in G$ is a solution. $b$ must be of the form $g^k$ for some $0 \leq k \leq 11 $. Therefore, we have

$$ (g^k)^2 = g^3 \implies g^{2k} = g^3 \implies g^{2k - 3} = e \implies |g|  \; \; \text{divides} \; \; 2k - 3$$

In other words, $|g|n_0 = 2k - 3 $ for some $n_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$. But I dont see how I can get a contradiction from here. Any suggestion will greatly be appreaciated. thanks

Comment: $3=2k-|g|n_0$. Right hand side is even( since $|g|=12$), but left hand side is odd, a contradiction.

Comment: how do you know $|g| = 12$? $|g|$ is order of an element

Comment: your cyclic group is of order 12 generated by $g$ right?

Comment: If $x^2 = g^3$, isn't it true that $x^8 = g^{12} = e$ and this tells something about the order of element $x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your group is isomorphic to the additive group $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, transposing to an additive notation, your problem is to solve the equation $x + x = a$ in this group. It should be clear now that your equation has no solution for $a = 1$.

Comment: In the original setting, this gives you $a=g$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an abelian group $G$; then the map $f\colon G\to G$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$ is a homomorphism.

If $G$ is finite of even order, then $f$ is not injective (why?), so it's not surjective either. An element in $G\setminus f(G)$ is a solution to your problem.

For cyclic groups it's even easier; suppose $g$ is a generator of $G$, with even order $n$. If $g=h^2$, what would be the order of $h$?